# Using existing ".so" file (created on Linux) in Android

Tags: android, linux

I have a `.so` file that was created on Linux (Ubuntu). I don't have its source.

I want to use same `.so` file on Android. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile your lib for arm processor to run on Andriod phone.

Answer (score 0):

The .so file you created is compiled for `32bit` or `64bit` `processors`, To make it work on Android you must have to compile it for `arm processor` as mentioned in other answers. you can use `Android NDK` to cross compile your lib with android tool chains. you also need to provide **CFLAGS**, **CPPFLAGS** and **LDFLAGS** according to arm processor.

Comment: one may argue that android can run on x86 devices as well.

Comment: @njzk2: I am completely agree with your argument. we use --arch parameter to generate architecture specific .so files. if you want to compile it for x86 Android or Google TV you can make it with Android NDK tool chain. But here in Question i think architecture is not mentioned.

Comment: that's right. Also, i wonder how would work a binary built for linux on a x86 android (one which would be using only basic functions)

Comment: damnit. i would have thought that basic libraries were pretty much same?

Comment: yeah. i don't know. stuff you'd expect to find on any linux-like environment.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. If you dont have the source code you cannot use it in Android. If you have source code build it for ARM and you can use..